# German and French words for "basic sequence"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, translation-request, mathematical-french, mathematical-german

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Definitions) says that a sequence $(x_n)$ is a basic sequence iff it is a Schauder basis of its closed linear span. I was wondering whether there is a French or German word for 'basic sequence'? How would you translate this into these two languages?

If you just know how to translate it into one of these languages, this would be extremely helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The German translation is simply "Basisfolge", see e.g. these [lectures notes](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/chenetzer/pdfs/BRT.pdf) (Definition 1.7).

Answer (score -1):

In French, the word "sequence" is translated by "suite" and "basic sequence" by "suite basique".